# Migrating old myUser.class.php / sfBasicSecurityUser to Symfony2?

Tags: authentication, symfony

I've written several Symfony 1.x projects that use a custom app/frontend/myUser.class.php (which extends sfBasicSecurityUser) to verify the login against a legacy user database.

Now I'd like to start with Symfony2 but I'm not quite sure where to hook my custom authentication in. I probably only need the authentication part and let Symfony do the
authorization.

Is there some quick migration tutorial somewhere? Or do I have to completely rewrite it according to the security chapter in The Book?

thanks,

-christian-